# PHP - Connect database remotely using IP address

Tags: php, database, connection, ip, host

How can I connect to my remote database using ip address? I have this code but evetime I load my site I get an error Could not connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx:80'

```
define ('DB_USER', 'user');
define ('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define ('DB_HOST', 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx:80');
define ('DB_NAME', 'databaseName'); 
$dbc=mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) 
    OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: '.mysql_error()); @mysql_select_db (DB_NAME) 
    OR die ('Could not select the database" '.mysql_error());;
```

Comment: What about port 3306?

Comment: Usually port 80 is used for webservers.

Comment: Thanks I will try port 3306

Answer (score 2):

Try using port 3306 instead:

```
define ('DB_HOST', 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3306');
```

Port 3306 is the default MySQL port, whereas port 80 is HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

The database server must be made available for remote access. As the usual MySQL server has no encryption, and it would generally be more of a security issue to make such a server available for the whole internet, any hosted mysql server usually is only available from the local network, if at all.

Check with your hosting company if you can access the database server from outside.

After that answer is yes, you must also know that user accounts in MySQL are not only username/password, but also contain a "source IP" component (which can be a wildcard "*", but usually is not), so there is another layer of protection to allow only dedicated IP addresses to gain access. Do you have a dynamic IP? That might be another problem to be solved.

Comment: I am using a static.. the IP of my router..then routes it to port 3306

Comment: Then routes it to the pc where my remote database is located.

Comment: Are you saying that your setup is more complicated that you stated in your question? Having some NAT device in the chain might affect things. And you didn't say something to the accound IP setting you are using.

Comment: I am using the roter's static IP then port forward when port is used 3306  to my pc where the database is.

Comment: And why are you going to port 80?

Comment: Because if i use port 80 it also forwards to the local database only if i typed the ip address with the port in the web address bar..but dor connections thru php it doesn't connect

Comment: Port 80 usually is for HTTP communication. And if "something" works when you type into a browser address bar, I suppose you connected to a HTTP based database administration tool. This is not the same as a direct MySQL connection, it cannot work that way.

Comment: I have used port 3306 and this is the error. "Could not connect to MySQL: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.hostingprod.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: Good, and now we are at the point I was mentioning in my answer: MySQL must allow connections from IPs. It isn't enough to have an account, it must be an account FOR THAT IP you are connecting from. And you need the MySQL port be open from your IP as well, but I think you checked that while fiddling with the port forwarding, didn't you?

Comment: Is it the host problem in the database wherein I have to change the localhost to '%' host?

Comment: Yes, if you want that the whole internet should be able to hack your db account. Otherwise, duplicate the existing account for localhost and add the IP you are using - or add % as a wildcard at the end of the first part of your IP.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies

Answer (score 0):

If using port 3306, like the other answer says, still doesn't give you a connection, you could try two things:

Look in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. You might find a line like this:

```
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment it out by putting a "#" in front.
If that still didn't help, check if the user you are trying to connect with is allowed to connect from all hosts.

Oh, and another thing: Don't use PHP's mysql library. Use PDO or mysqli instead, as the mysql library is deprecated.

Comment: PS i am using xampp..where can i find the /etc/mysql/my.cnf?

Comment: Type `mysql --help` in command line, in the output block that follows there's a block of text which says which config file is used. Usually, it's `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`.

Comment: Thanks. the bind-address           = 127.0.0.1 already has been commented out as default. I will try the PDO or mysqli

Comment: Where can I check if user is allowed to connect from all hosts?

Comment: Check the table user in database "mysql". If the user you're trying to connect with only has host "localhost", you can't connect with it from the outside. Change that to "%".

Comment: is it available in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Where can I check users tables?

Comment: DB "mysql", table "user", field "host"

Comment: I have change "localhost" to "%" but my site appears to be blank.

Comment: I login to  phpmyadmin

Answer (score -1):

Try using the default port number: 3306

Comment: Could not connect to MySQL: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.hostingprod.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server